# Sentence fragment: subject or object

Tags: subjects, objects, sentence-fragments

Suppose I have a picture of me hanging out with Bob, and I want to add a caption to it. Is one of the following more correct than the other?

1. "Bob and me"
2. "Bob and I"

More generally, do grammar rules apply to sentence fragments at all?

Comment: Don't forget (3) _me and Bob_ and (4) _I and Bob_.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, it's a sentence fragment. It doesn't really matter which you choose, the choice is more a matter of style, than of correctness.

But we can look at what would be usual.

If you change the context, and say you're trying to identify an unknown person, and you have a bunch of photos. Would you say *"Here's another one of bob and he."? I certainly wouldn't.

So since your fragment is probably an elision of "This is a photo of Bob and me.", it's clear one would most often use an object, not a subject.

Comment: Why not *This is Bob and I*? Or *Here are Bob and I*?

Comment: Because, as I said above, you would not say *"this is bob and he". *I* vs *me* is an analogous situation.

Comment: To be overly pedantic, because "is" is a linking verb, "This is I" is correct, and "This is me" is actually incorrect.

Comment: @blf If you already know the answer, why ask the question? Usage dictates "correctness" and what is "correct" changes over time. You can see that in [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+is+I%2C+this+is+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)